# Html 5 canvas rectangle removing and after draw

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawrectangle

I tried  to draw a rectangle ,erase it and redraw another rectangle in a canvas.
The result of this three operation is that there are two rectangle .

Html 5 api javascript  : http://pastebin.com/Qgf38C7m

```
function Oggetto(idname,nome,posizione_x,posizione_y,width,height,doption){
        this.nome                       =       nome            ;      
        this.posizione_x        =       posizione_x     ;
        this.posizione_y        =       posizione_y     ;
        this.width                      =       width           ;
        this.height                     =       height          ;
        this.doption            =       doption         ;
        this.idname                     =       idname          ;
        console.log(this.idname);
        this.context            =       document.getElementById(idname).getContext("2d");      
}
Oggetto.prototype.draw = function () {
};
Oggetto.prototype.clear = function () {
};



function Entita(idname,nome,posizione_x,posizione_y,width,height,doption){
        Oggetto.call(this,idname,nome,posizione_x,posizione_y,width,height,doption);
}
Entita.prototype.draw = function (){
        this.context.rect(this.posizione_x,this.posizione_y,this.width,this.height);
        this.context.stroke();
};
Entita.prototype.clear = function () {
        // this.context.clearRect(this.posizione_x, this.posizione_y, this.width, this.height);
     //Richiamo il metodo per la creazione di un rettangolo con background
     this.context.clearRect(this.posizione_x-4, this.posizione_y-4, this.width+10, this.height+10);

};
Entita.prototype.enlarge = function (w,h) {
         this.clear();
         this.width             =       w;
         this.height    =       h;
         this.draw();
};
Entita.prototype =  new  Oggetto();
```

javascript code that call it :

```
 e =new Entita("ke","pio",10,10,100,100,"prova");   
 e.draw();
 e.enlarge(400,200);
```

Result:
[image: http://postimg.org/image/vpgg20nyt/]

Comment: i tried it with chrome and mozilla firefox.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(this.posizione_x-4, this.posizione_y-4, this.width+10, this.height+10);` ? (does it match the rect you draw first)

Comment: what is `this.context` ? I don't see it initialized?

Comment: Sorry all code is this .  http://pastebin.com/XAd0Zv1Q

Comment: Oggetto constructor is called two times the first time all parameter is undefined(for prototype i think ) the second time for e instance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the **current working path** to draw your rectangle, you need to reset the current working path with `beginPath`. Otherwise, you're just adding new subpaths to the current working path, which is why both rectangles are drawn on using `stroke` in `Entitia.draw`.

You could always just go with `strokeRect` to avoid any confusion with the filling/stroking the current working path, but if you plan to add arbitrary shapes in the future, your best bet is to simply add the line `this.context.beginPath()` as the first statement for `Entitia.draw`.

```
Entita.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.context.beginPath();
    //Other statements for defining
    //current working path and stroking/filling
    //it
};
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gweah/)**.